# Hadoop. localhost:9000: connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, hadoop, connection, порт

Datanode не может подключиться к namenode через порт 9000. Сервера спокойно пингуются, но вот порт 9000 выдаёт "Connection refused".

Так указан адрес у меня в core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Система: Ubuntu server 23.10

Замена localhost на цифровой адрес не могла, отключение ufw тоже не дало результатов.

Answer (score 1):

Решение довольно простое. Использовать адрес: "0.0.0.0:9000".

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Я не знаю, почему не нашлось ответа на этот вопрос, возможно это особенность именно последней ubuntu.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` - это "любой адрес данной машины"

Comment: Согласен, что плохое решение, но я хз что еще сделать

Comment: Да я не про это, я просто уточняю смысл. Может это и правильное решение, я не знаю.

Comment: На самом деле не правильное, так webhdfs не заведется, но с другими решениями вообще ничего работать не будет

Answer (score 1):

Я смог решить проблему полностью, как это должно быть.

У меня /etc/hosts выглядел так:

```
127.0.0.1           localhost master
<hostname ip>       master
<other ip>          slave
...
```

или так:

```
127.0.0.1           localhost
127.0.0.1           master
<other ip>          slave
...
```

Надо изменить на это:

```
127.0.0.1           localhost
<hostname ip>       master
<other ip>          slave
```

и в core-site прописать ip, который выдает hostname (не имя, а именно цифровой ipv4)